# Bing maps control hangs the back navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I recently ran into weird bug in Bing map control. In short, if the connection is poor and you press the hardware back button on page with map while the map is still loading some tiles, the navigation process hangs up (some times up to 10 or even more seconds). And in case when the time is more than 3 seconds the app will be "a little" not user-friendly and will not meet the technical certification requirements (5.1.3).

To repeat the bug you can create the app with two pages. First one with button to navigate to the second page. And the second page with just map control with high ZoomLevel (more than 14 for example). After the app launches, you navigate to the second page and move map to some unloaded area and then (without waiting for the download to complete) press the hardware back button. And also you somehow must "create poor" connection (in my case, simply disconnecting the device from the computer is enough).

And does anyone have any idea why this occurs and how to workaround it?

**EDIT**: The same bug can be observed in the Foursquare application for wp7 - if you go to the page where the place is shown on the map in full screen, then slide the map into an unloaded region and press the hardware button back.

It seems that the problem is in the Bing Map Control.

Comment: what you can do is add a loaded event to map and in that event gradually increase the zoom level...

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'v tried, but sill no lock. The problem remains.

In this case the top-level tiles are loaded. However, if then in high-level zoom you slide the map to their area and press the hardware back button... navigation still freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the Maps control using the Visibility first, before you navigate out of the page. That way the control will become inactive and memory consumption of the page will decrease, thus allowing to switch pages faster.

Comment: The map control visibility is nearly first thing that I've tried. And as result - Setting the map visibility to collapsed in OnNavigatedFrom method wouldn't help. 

Also traditional "nohow" solution and some info on the issue can be obtained here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/7ab6a447-8b0a-431e-993e-a38bd67509da